# Possibility of processes getting stuck in the consumer when producers have finished producing?

Tags: c, process, producer-consumer, consumer, producer

I was thinking about the consumer and producer problem. Suppose you have two semaphores, one to keep track of the number of spaces (sem_t spaces) and one to keep track of the number of items in the buffer (sem_t items). Now there are multiple producers are consumers.

If the buffer is empty (meaning there are no items), the multiple consumer processes would have to wait for the producer to produce more items. Let's say the producer finishes producing the last item (post(items))so that the producers no longer get called.

Now would one only 1 consumer be able to pass the semaphore (wait(items)) and the rest of the semaphores would still be stuck on wait(items) since the producers stopped producing? Is this a possibility? How would one get around this?

Sorry if this didn't make any sense. I am just thinking about this problem. Let me know if I can clarify in any way.

Comment: If the producers stop producing then having the consumers wait until they start up again is one valid behaviour so that's not automatically wrong. If you want the consumers to end then you need to notify them when such an event arises. How to do the notification is implementation/system specific. For example, if you are using pthreads then sending a signal to each consumer process will break it out of any `sem_wait` call. Or you can use a wait API that has timeout.

Comment: But if there are multiple consumers waiting on wait(items) already, how would you send that signal to notify them to stop if they are being blocked at the moment?

Comment: One of the producers would send the signal not the consumers that are blocked.

Comment: Since the consumers are waiting (blocked), how would they receive the signal. I am supposed to use processes, no threads. Sorry if I am not understanding this correctly by the way.

Comment: Queue up an item that instructs a consumer to terminate.  When a consumer gets such an item, it requeues it and terminates.  The 'poison' item is then picked up by another consumer, and so on, until all consumers are terminated.  If you are queueing pointers to items, a null makes a good poison pill because it does not need to be freed/destroyed/whatever when it has done its work.

Comment: One problem I have is that I have already implemented a stack, and this is somewhat harder to coordinate than a queue. I am having trouble thinking of a way to push(terminating item), but there still might be some items in the stack that the consumers haven't yet consumed.

Comment: @SteamedBun pop them and destroy them.